# Periodically connected QHO's

Tags: symmetry, harmonic-oscillator, dispersion

I've recently been thinking about what happens when you connect quantum harmonic oscillators in a periodic way. I'm actually thinking about when you take a mass-spring system (which can easily be put in the second quant. framework) and you connect each system to the next one with another spring, a coupling spring. Then, you connect the final one to the first one again. Say say you have three, then spring 1 is connected to 2 and 3, spring 2 to 1 and 3, and 3 to 2 and 1. I'm interested in the type of mode structure these systems will exhibit, and also in the type of dispersion relation you expect from this. A periodic structure of capacitively coupled RLC circuits would be the same of course, so this is also fine.

My original question was where should I start in analysing such a system, especially if I want to look at the dispersion relation? While in a way this is similar to the tight binding model for solids, I'm not sure this is exactly the direction I should take.

However, I'm also quite sure that this would have been studied in the past, but I am not able to find any literature on this. So I'm also definitely looking for some references on this. In the comments someone was already helpful enough to provide a rather advanced source, and all I can find is papers of such level, but nothing more basic.

I should actually stress that I'm talking about a system of quantum harmonic oscillators (which are already oscillators on their own), which are then coupled to each other. This is definitely similar but different from phonons, as I'm talking about a Hamiltonian of the form

$$H = \sum_i{\hbar\omega_i(\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_i+\frac{1}{2})} + \sum_{i}{\hbar J_{i,i+1}\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_{i+1}}+hc$$

and not $$H = \sum_i{\hbar\omega_i(\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_i+\frac{1}{2})}$$

Comment: There is a pretty large literature on harmonic chains, including those with periodic boundary conditions. [See here](http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-6596/128/1/012028) for example. I would expect that you should be able to diagonalise the Hamiltonian exactly by first writing in terms of creation and annihilation operators, and then performing a Bogoliubov transformation. Alternatively you can first find the normal modes of the classical Hamiltonian and then quantise these directly, which should give the same result.

Comment: Right, very interesting, thanks. The paper is already quite a bit more advanced than what I am thinking of, as they investigate non-canonical solutions. What I'm looking for is more the actual canonical ones, but they don't seem to explicitly cite a paper in which this is looked at.

Comment: You can probably find the canonical solution for a quadratic harmonic network in many condensed matter texts, for example, since this leads to a basic microscopic model of quantised phonons in crystalline solids.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I apologize for not replying, somehow it slipped my mind. Phonons are a good case study, but that is really the case of individual masses connected with springs. What I'd rather look at is really individual oscillators, connected with each other. So a more clear example would be (quantum) pendulums, connected with springs. Or well, the case I'm actually interested in, RLC circuits that are connected to each other capacitively. I think maybe this was not clear enough in my post, what do you think?

Comment: So this is the same as your other question, right? If you choose the coupling to be as you have written, the problem is identical to your other question. A more natural coupling for oscillators is $\hat{x}_i\hat{x}_j$, which is slightly more tricky because of the $a^\dagger_i a^\dagger_j$ terms. Nevertheless, any problem bilinear in bosonic operators for $N$ oscillators can be solved exactly in principle simply by diagonalising matrices of size $N\times N$.

Comment: Well in essence it is I suppose. The other question is more literally on how to actually perform the calculation, while here I'm more asking about some general references/information on such system. You are right that I can indeed find such couplings (like in optics and such) and they are well studied, but somehow I feel this system will definitely have been looked at too. I do indeed agree that you can find the eigenvalues by diagonalising the matrix. I do not however see how you could get the analytical (but horrible complicted) generalisation of the cosine in the dispersion relation.

Comment: I should add that maybe I should merge the two questions, as they are too related to be on their own, I agree with you on that.

Comment: I am not saying "analytical", just "exact" ;) I would diagonalise the matrix in MATLAB or equivalent for a large system. The eigenvalues give you the dispersion relation, and you're done. Note that it's not really a "dispersion relation" when the system is not translation invariant. However, close to translation-invariance you should be able to calculate e.g. group velocities and so on by taking numerical derivatives. Obviously you can also do this all with pen and paper if you are really feeling masochistic... But yes I would say these two questions are identical and should be merged.

Comment: I almost follow, except for the fact that while you might get the eigenvalues, you don't know to which k value they belong, right? Or is that when you fourier transform the eigenvectors, see for what k they are maximal, and use that? So in that case there is no curve like the cosine, but just the points on the generalization of that cosine?

Comment: The k value is just an index labelling the eigenvalues. This only corresponds to a momentum in the translation-invariant case, where you know the analytical solution anyway. This is why I said it is not strictly a dispersion relation when the system is not translation-invariant. Close to translation-invariance, your Fourier transform idea is a good one, although it will need to be interpreted with some caution since momentum is not a good quantum number.

Comment: Right, I see. However, in the other post I also mentioned the completely coupled case, $$H = \sum_i{\hbar\omega(\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_i+\frac{1}{2})} + \sum_{i \neq j}{\hbar J\hat{a}^\dagger_i\hat{a}_{j}}+hc$$. Here you do retain translation invariance, without knowing the analytic solution. Should I then use the approach I mention above?

Comment: Yeah that seems like it could give you some insight.